# Cannot Install GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;3) OSX

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, sdk, gpu

Can somebody help me, I want to install GPU debugging tool version 3.1.0 on my android studio OSX, but installation did not complete successfully and **this is the log :**

Packages to install: 
- GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;3)

Preparing "Install GPU Debugging tools (revision: 3.1.0)".
Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gapid_2994895_osx.zip
This download could not be finalized from the interim state. Retrying without caching.

Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/gapid_2994895_osx.zip
Failed packages:
- GPU Debugging tools (extras;android;gapid;3)

I deleted folder gapid, but the result still the same

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with NDK 20.0.5594570. I've got an error when I've tried to install it from Android Studio 3.6.1. And it worked when I tried to install it via command line sdkmanager https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager

Comment: This also worked for me.

sdkmanager as located in sdk/tools/bin

command was: ./sdkmanager "extras;android;gapid;3"